# Is there a replacement for query.yahooapis.com YQL service that was just shut down?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

I was unaware that Yahoo was EOL'ing their YQL service and we have an intranet website that depends on it. Does anyone know of a replacement for this functionality, or perhaps a free dot.Net library that can help replicate this functionality? See https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/